# Get Android to treat HTML Select like Android Spinner?

Tags: android, html, select, android-spinner

Android Spinner GUI component is a typical droplist with autocomplete. 
HTML5 select with a datalist is too, but unfortunately, HTML5 with datalist in Android is **NOT**.

Of course Android won't support datalist until next year (they claim). More importantly, any HTML select is a hack-job Android thing on a tablet. On a phone, its OK. On the tablet, the select is not a drop down but a short list slides up at the bottom of the screen. That list has radio buttons and a Done button. Its a weird little UI component which warts into the screen instead of a drop list displaying. Is there are way to tell Android to do the right thing?  To treat this like one does in a web browser on a desktop?

I have used the jQuery UI droplist and it is OK on a tablet but then bad on a phone. On the phone the keyboard comes up and blocks the display. Is there any way to tell Android to do the right thing? To not show the keyboard for this particular html input element?

Can I tell Android to:

1. Not show keyboard for some elements?
2. Not do that stupid iPad-style wart but do html select's like a normal browser, and like they do their own droplist Spinner?

Comment: phonegap versus old Xamarin app

Comment: I _think_ you can make the input `readonly` when it is focused and let jQuery UI do its job. Theoretically, the keyboard should not display for readonly fields.

Comment: @maxweber did you try the approach I had described in my answer?

Comment: Hi Kiril, no, as I know about that one. But, yours is the best answer. Trying to figure out how to accept it. Bottom line, one more broken thing by Google. They truly are Microsoft 1999. I think they have a few more innovations before they become worthless to advancement though.

Comment: BTW, looking at competitors apps, they never figured this stuff out either. When they phonegap it, the keyboard comes over the top of the amount field and such. That's a Fortune 50 company who can't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little bit hacky but it is possible. You have to create a `javascript` bridge between the `WebView` and your `java` code.

```
class JsBridge {
   @JavascriptInterface
   public void showNativeSpinner() {
       // show native spinner logic
   }
}

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsBridge(), "jsBridge");
```

In your `html` code you have to remove/hide the `select` and add somekind of placeholder that can be clicked. Disabling the `select` won't work because disabled element cannot receive events (cannot be clicked). And then attach a `onclick` callback that triggers the bridge method. All of this can be done using javascript.

```
$("#my-select").hide();
$("#my-select-parent").append("<div id='placeholder'></div>");
$("#placeholder").on("click", function() {
    jsBridge.showNativeSpinner();
});
```

You can execute ``` javascript`` code to the ```WebView`from the`java``` code this way

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:yourLogicFunction()");
```

The last thing you should to is to add an `OnItemSelectedListener` to the spinner and in the listener method to call `javascript` callbacks in the `WebView` using the `loadUrl` method again.

This should solve your problem :)